# _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name in Python

Tags: python, tkinter-entry, customtkinter

This is my debut on this site, so I will start short with introducing myself. I’m Thomas from Denmark, I hold a bachelor's degree in construction engineering and I’m trying to learn to program in Python in my spare time. So, it’s fair to say that I’m a bit of a dumbass when it comes to programming, so I hope you guys can help me.

I have attached two images of the program so it’s easier to imagine what’s going on.

My issue with the program is that when I set any one of the entry fields to an empty string, I get an TclError. But this only happens if it’s the second time I have created that frame “ForsideMenuFrame” or “LastarrangementMenuFrame”. So, I think it has something to do with when I destroy the frames. I do it to “clean up” after myself so the program performs better, or at least that is what I think.
The message I get in the output is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_entry.py", line 121, in _textvariable_callback
    self._activate_placeholder()
  File "C:\Users\Thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_entry.py", line 299, in _activate_placeholder
    if self._entry.get() == "" and self._placeholder_text is not None and (self._textvariable is None or self._textvariable == ""):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3109, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!lastarrangementmenuframe.!ctkentry.!entry"
```

The program does not crash, it still functions the way I want it to, it just bugs me, and I can’t figure out how to prevent it.

Below you see a copy of my code, and the images should be attached in the buttom.

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import settings, forside, lastarrangement, tagudformning

class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        # Setup
        super().__init__(fg_color = settings.BACKGROUND_COLOR)
        self.title('Snelaster')
        self.geometry('1400x850+50+3')
        self._set_appearance_mode('dark')
        self.iconbitmap('Snow_flake.ico')
        self.resizable(False, False)

        # Layout
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1, uniform = 'a')
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight = 24, uniform = 'a')
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1, uniform = 'a')
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight = 3, uniform = 'a')

        # Dictionary for frames
        self.frames = {
            'forside_menu': None,
            'forside_screen': None,
            'forside_header': None,
            'lastarrangement_menu': None,
            'lastarrangement_screen': None,
            'lastarrangement_header': None,
            'pulttag_menu': None,
            'pulttag_screen': None,
            'pulttag_header': None,
            'sadeltag_menu': None,
            'sadeltag_screen': None,
            'sadeltag_header': None}
        
        # Dictionary for StringVars
        self.string_vars = {
            'entry_sag': ctk.StringVar(),
            'entry_sagsnr': ctk.StringVar(),
            'entry_initialer': ctk.StringVar(),
            'entry_dato': ctk.StringVar()}
        
        # Dictionary for StringVars with tracing
        self.traced_string_vars01 = {
            'entry_C_t': ctk.StringVar(value = '1.0'),
            'combobox_C_top': ctk.StringVar(value = 'Normal'),
            'label_C_top': ctk.StringVar(value = 'C_top\t=\t1.00'),
            'entry_l_1': ctk.StringVar(value = ''),
            'entry_l_2': ctk.StringVar(value = ''),
            'entry_h': ctk.StringVar(value = ''),
            'label_C_s': ctk.StringVar(value = 'C_s\t=\t1.00'),
            'label_C_e': ctk.StringVar(value = 'C_e\t=\t1.00')}
        
        # Start tracing of StringVars
        self.start_trace_string_vars01()

        # Instance of ButtonFrame
        self.button_frame = ButtonFrame(self)
        self.forside_button_click()

        # Run
        self.mainloop()

    # Button commands
    def forside_button_click(self):
        # Change button colors
        self.button_frame.forside_button.configure(fg_color = settings.FORSIDEHEADER_FRAME_COLOR_DARK)
        self.button_frame.lastarrangement_button.configure(fg_color = settings.LASTARRANGEMENTHEADER_FRAME_COLOR)
        self.button_frame.formfaktor_button.configure(fg_color = settings.FORMFAKTORHEADER_FRAME_COLOR)

        # Destroying exsisting frames
        self.destroy_frames()

        # Creating Forside Menu Frame   
        self.frames['forside_menu'] = forside.ForsideMenuFrame(self,
                                                               self.string_vars['entry_sag'],
                                                               self.string_vars['entry_sagsnr'],
                                                               self.string_vars['entry_initialer'],
                                                               self.string_vars['entry_dato'])
        
        # Creating Forside Screen Frame
        self.frames['forside_screen'] = forside.ForsideScreenFrame(self)

        # Creating Forside Header Frame
        self.frames['forside_header'] = forside.ForsideHeaderFrame(self)

    def lastarrangement_button_click(self):
        # Change button colors
        self.button_frame.forside_button.configure(fg_color = settings.FORSIDEHEADER_FRAME_COLOR)
        self.button_frame.lastarrangement_button.configure(fg_color = settings.LASTARRANGEMENTHEADER_FRAME_COLOR_DARK)
        self.button_frame.formfaktor_button.configure(fg_color = settings.FORMFAKTORHEADER_FRAME_COLOR)

        # Destroying exsisting frames
        self.destroy_frames()

        # Creating Lastarrangement Menu Frame
        self.frames['lastarrangement_menu'] = lastarrangement.LastarrangementMenuFrame(self,
                                                                                       self.traced_string_vars01['entry_C_t'],
                                                                                       self.traced_string_vars01['combobox_C_top'],
                                                                                       self.traced_string_vars01['label_C_top'],
                                                                                       self.traced_string_vars01['entry_l_1'],
                                                                                       self.traced_string_vars01['entry_l_2'],
                                                                                       self.traced_string_vars01['entry_h'],
                                                                                       self.traced_string_vars01['label_C_s'],
                                                                                       self.traced_string_vars01['label_C_e'])

        # Creating Lastarrangement Screen Frame
        self.frames['lastarrangement_screen'] = lastarrangement.LastarrangementScreenFrame(self)

        # Creating Lastarrangement Header Frame
        self.frames['lastarrangement_header'] = lastarrangement.LastarrangementHeaderFrame(self)

    def formfaktor_button_click(self):
        # Change button colors
        self.button_frame.forside_button.configure(fg_color = settings.FORSIDEHEADER_FRAME_COLOR)
        self.button_frame.lastarrangement_button.configure(fg_color = settings.LASTARRANGEMENTHEADER_FRAME_COLOR)
        self.button_frame.formfaktor_button.configure(fg_color = settings.FORMFAKTORHEADER_FRAME_COLOR_DARK)

        # Destroying exsisting frames
        self.destroy_frames()

        # Creating Formfaktor Menu Frame
        self.frames['pulttag_menu'] = tagudformning.PulttagMenuFrame(self)

        # Creating Formfaktor Screen Frame
        self.frames['pulttag_screen'] = tagudformning.PulttagScreenFrame(self)

        # Creating Formfaktor Header Frame
        self.frames['pulttag_header'] = tagudformning.PulttagHeaderFrame(self)

    def destroy_frames(self):
        for key, value in self.frames.items():
            if value is not None:
                # Destroying the frame
                self.frames[key].destroy()
                self.frames[key] = None

    def start_trace_string_vars01(self):
        for value in self.traced_string_vars01.values():
            value.trace('w', self.trace_string_vars01)

    def trace_string_vars01(self, *args):
        # entry_C_t
        C_t = self.traced_string_vars01['entry_C_t'].get()
        if len(C_t) == 2 and C_t[0] == '0' and C_t[1] != '.' or len(C_t) > 0 and C_t[0] == '.':
            self.traced_string_vars01['entry_C_t'].set('0')
        try:
            C_t = float(C_t)
            if C_t > 1:
                self.traced_string_vars01['entry_C_t'].set('1.0')
        except ValueError:
            if C_t == '':
                pass
            else:
                self.traced_string_vars01['entry_C_t'].set('')

        # label_C_top
        topografi = self.traced_string_vars01['combobox_C_top'].get()
        C_top = 1.00
        if topografi == 'Afskærmet':
            C_top = 1.25
        elif topografi == 'Normal':
            C_top = 1.00
        elif topografi == 'Vindblæst':
            C_top = 0.80
        self.traced_string_vars01['label_C_top'].set(f'C_top\t=\t{C_top:.2f}')

        # entry l_1
        l_1 = self.traced_string_vars01['entry_l_1'].get()
        if len(l_1) == 2 and l_1[0] == '0' and l_1[1] != '.' or len(l_1) > 0 and l_1[0] == '.':
            self.traced_string_vars01['entry_l_1'].set('')
        try:
            l_1 = float(l_1)
        except ValueError:
            if l_1 == '':
                pass
            else:
                self.traced_string_vars01['entry_l_1'].set('')

        # entry l_2
        l_2 = self.traced_string_vars01['entry_l_2'].get()
        if len(l_2) == 2 and l_2[0] == '0' and l_2[1] != '.' or len(l_2) > 0 and l_2[0] == '.':
            self.traced_string_vars01['entry_l_2'].set('')
        try:
            l_2 = float(l_2)
        except ValueError:
            if l_2 == '':
                pass
            else:
                self.traced_string_vars01['entry_l_2'].set('')

        # entry h
        h = self.traced_string_vars01['entry_h'].get()
        if len(h) == 2 and h[0] == '0' and h[1] != '.' or len(h) > 0 and h[0] == '.':
            self.traced_string_vars01['entry_h'].set('')
        try:
            h = float(h)
        except ValueError:
            if h == '':
                pass
            else:
                self.traced_string_vars01['entry_h'].set('')

        # label C_s
        try:
            C_s = 1.00
            if topografi == 'Afskærmet':
                C_s = 1.00
            elif 2 * h > l_1:
                C_s = 1.00
            else:
                if l_2 <= 10 * h:
                    C_s = 1.00
                elif l_2 >= 20 * h:
                    C_s = 1.25
                else:
                    C_s = 1 + 0.025 * ((l_2 - 10 * h) / h)
            self.traced_string_vars01['label_C_s'].set(f'C_s\t=\t{C_s:.2f}')
        except TypeError:
            pass

        # label C_e
        C_e = C_top * C_s
        self.traced_string_vars01['label_C_e'].set(f'C_e\t=\t{C_e:.2f}')
    
class ButtonFrame(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # Setup
        super().__init__(master = parent, 
                         fg_color = settings.BUTTON_FRAME_COLOR)
        self.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'nsew')

        # Create instance of parent (App)
        self.parent = parent

        # Layout
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1, uniform = 'a')
        self.columnconfigure((0,1,2), weight = 1, uniform = 'a')

        # Button font
        font = ctk.CTkFont(family = settings.FONT_FAMILY,
                           size = settings.BUTTON_FONT_SIZE,
                           weight = 'bold')

        # Button widgets
        self.forside_button = ctk.CTkButton(self, 
                                       text = 'Forside', 
                                       font = font,
                                       text_color = 'white',
                                       fg_color = settings.FORSIDEHEADER_FRAME_COLOR,
                                       hover_color = settings.FORSIDEHEADER_FRAME_COLOR_DARK,
                                       corner_radius = settings.BUTTON_CORNER_RADIUS,
                                       command = self.parent.forside_button_click)
        self.forside_button.grid(row = 0, column = 0, 
                                 sticky = 'nsew')

        self.lastarrangement_button = ctk.CTkButton(self, 
                                               text = 'Lastarrangement', 
                                               font = font,
                                               text_color = 'white',
                                               fg_color = settings.LASTARRANGEMENTHEADER_FRAME_COLOR,
                                               hover_color = settings.LASTARRANGEMENTHEADER_FRAME_COLOR_DARK,
                                               corner_radius = settings.BUTTON_CORNER_RADIUS,
                                               command = self.parent.lastarrangement_button_click)
        self.lastarrangement_button.grid(row = 0, column = 1, 
                                         sticky = 'nsew')

        self.formfaktor_button = ctk.CTkButton(self, 
                                          text = 'Formfaktor', 
                                          font = font,
                                          text_color = 'white',
                                          fg_color = settings.FORMFAKTORHEADER_FRAME_COLOR,
                                          hover_color = settings.FORMFAKTORHEADER_FRAME_COLOR_DARK,
                                          corner_radius = settings.BUTTON_CORNER_RADIUS,
                                          command = self.parent.formfaktor_button_click)
        self.formfaktor_button.grid(row = 0, column = 2, 
                                    sticky = 'nsew')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App()
```

[Forside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVYcq.png)
[Lastarrangement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1K1z.png)

This is what I have tried, and it did not work. In the start of the program, I imported _tkinter.

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import settings, forside, lastarrangement, tagudformning
import _tkinter as _tk
```

And then in the trace_string_vars01 method of the App class I tried to except a TclError and then ignored it.

```
 # entry_C_t
        try:
            C_t = self.traced_string_vars01['entry_C_t'].get()
            if len(C_t) == 2 and C_t[0] == '0' and C_t[1] != '.' or len(C_t) > 0 and C_t[0] == '.':
                self.traced_string_vars01['entry_C_t'].set('0')
            try:
                C_t = float(C_t)
                if C_t > 1:
                    self.traced_string_vars01['entry_C_t'].set('1.0')
            except ValueError:
                if C_t == '':
                    pass
                else:
                    self.traced_string_vars01['entry_C_t'].set('')
        except _tk.TclError:
            pass
```

Comment: Great work, thank you for including the code and the screenshots :) I'm a mechanical engineer and I love the clean design. I can't promise I'll look at it today, but at least you gave anyone willing to help a good starting point.

Comment: As far as I can tell, none of your code, other than the call to the event loop, is on the call stack when the error happens, so the code you have that tries to catch and ignore the exception is not used at all.

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests it comes within the `costumtkinter` package and the source code give you multiple options where the error might happen.

Setting the variable to an [empty string](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/master/customtkinter/windows/widgets/ctk_entry.py#L119), by [configure placeholder](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/master/customtkinter/windows/widgets/ctk_entry.py#L231), [FocusOut](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/master/customtkinter/windows/widgets/ctk_entry.py#L319), [delete method](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/master/customtkinter/windows/widgets/ctk_entry.py#L327) or by [instantiating a Entry](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/master/customtkinter/windows/widgets/ctk_entry.py#L96).

Further, your error refering to this Entry:
`".!lastarrangementmenuframe.!ctkentry.!entry"`
Even though you included a lot of code, it's not enough in this case, since `lastarrangement.LastarrangementMenuFrame` is defined in an imported module.

The error:

> _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!lastarrangementmenuframe.!ctkentry.!entry"

means that you/the `StringVar` or an event refering to an already dead widget.

Comment: I didn’t provide you with the entire code, I thought it was not necessary. The imported modules you mention are just classes for each of the frames. So they just have the layout of the frames, and the widgets they contain.
The error starts to occur after I destroy some of the frames and then set the entry widget to an empty string.
As you mention the error comes from within the customtkinter package, and I’m kind of on deep water here, on how to approach this issue, when I think is an issue that is beyond my current level of competence. Maybe you could give some pointers to get me started?

Comment: @ThomasB The best approach should be to avoid referencing dead widgets of course. In my opinion you got a design flaw in your code. Dead widgets should be dead on the tcl and python interpreter. However, why are your widgets been destroyed before your application ends? It's rather rare that someone needs to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was doing it because in the first version of the program I didn’t destroy the frames, I was creating frame on frame on frame and so on, and then doing this enough time the program becomes kind of slow, so I tried this instead, with destroying them instead. Can I ask how you would manage this instead?

Comment: Again, thank you for your reply and effort @Thingamabobs. I get what you’re saying, and I will instead try a different approach where I forget the frames instead of destroying them. Your comment has helped me a lot, and I think it was the pointer I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @ThomasB you are welcome. Once you gathering enough reputation points, you can join the tkinter chat room on this site. I think you need 50 or 80 or something. Sometimes all you need is to talk to others